# appengine log console extremely slow

Tags: google-app-engine, logging, console, performance

I am using the python app engine and finding that the log console on the local development server is terribly slow.  Output to this window seems to show in chunks of about 5-15 lines every second.  Is that typical?  I find that it's so slow that it hinders my debugging time waiting for log data to appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose this may be as good an answer as any under the circumstance.  Basically, I closed and reopened google app engine launcher, and the outputting was back to being appropriately fast.  If anyone has a suggestion *why* this happens, that would be great.  For now, though, at least this makes the slowness go away.